# whats a good way of not getting site session variables mixed up with other sites under same domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, web, dns

basically on my web development server, i have several website projects going.  I ran into the issue where one of my website projects session variable was conflicting with another website project's session variable.  Both of those website projects are under the same server.  So is there a good way of distiungishing the variables between the website projects?  hope this makes sense...

also both of the websites are membership type websites, so i'm using the same session variables for the membership portion of the websites.

and both of the websites are on the codeigniter framework.  So using codeigniter, how do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use  [`session_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

Example :

```
  session_name("WebsiteID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session_name function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to give each site a unique session name. Read the notes carefully about when to set the session name (basically before any other session functions).

Another method would be to use the "path" feature to restrict to the path of your website (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). This way, the session cookie will only be visible to scripts on or beneath the path you set. (Make sure you delete any cookies at the "root" level first, as these will be visible but all sub-directories!)

Or if you're doing it manually with cookies, prefix the name of the cookie with something unique. SetCookie('WebsiteName_' . 'session', ID, time, path etc).

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to have a config file for each site, which I require_once in every php file.
In this config file I specify things like the DB parameters (user, password, etc) and a session header:
$config['sess_header']  = 'site1';

When I create or query the session I use this sess_header, for example:
$_SESSION[$config['sess_header']]['user_id'] = $user_id;